# Compass command is not recognized at Command Prompt on Windows 64

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, command-prompt, compass

I have installed on my Windows 64 system
- Global grunt, bower, handlebars
- Ruby Installer 2.2.3
- RubyGems 2.4.8
& gem install compass. 
Still Command Prompt does not recognize Compass command

It does recognize
Sass --v which is 3.4.18 and 
ruby --version which 2.2.3p173

I have also set the Environment Variables as desired.

On doing the grunt build using command prompt for my project; the following error is received.

```
Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task
```

Warning: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "compass.bat --version"
The system cannot find the path specified. Use --force to continue.

What wrong could I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a problem with `bin-version` dependency that `grunt-contrib-compass` internally uses. Check this issue https://github.com/sindresorhus/bin-version/issues/5

To solve the issue try uninstalling and then reinstalling the `grunt-contrib-compass` package

```
npm uninstall --save-dev grunt-contrib-compass
npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-compass
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But that didn't work. I think this is something to do with Windows 64

Comment: Could you check the version of the ``bin-version`` dependency in its package.json (It will be found inside *node_modules* > *grunt-contrib-compass* > *node_modules* > *bin-version-check* > *node_modules* > *bin-version* folder) ?

Comment: Also could you check in ``C:\Ruby22-x64\bin`` weather a file named ``compass`` and ``compass.bat`` is present ? If not present , then compass is not installed on you machine

Comment: package.json had this "bin-version-check": "^2.0.0"

Comment: Ruby/bin folder also contains compass and compass.bat

Comment: "compass" command is recognized when it is started with Ruby. I am able to run the build without any errors. However the issue still stands open because the "compass"
 command is not recognized at Command Prompt.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing Ruby, putting it on Path variable, closing the node cmd and opening it again. To test if your compass is installed, just open a CMD and execute "compass.bat" command, if it works, then the grunt will work too, you just have to close the cmd window and open it again.